# How can I make a C# vertical bar chart

Tags: c#, winforms, graphing

I'm using the'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting' library for my bar chart but the bars are horizontal rather than vertical.  I tried changing

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
```

[image]

to

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
```

[image: Bar]

but that didn't work at all as you can see from the 2nd screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
```

to

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
```

or choose from ASP.NET tags, read all types of data display charts

Comment: sorry didn't read next screenshot description, but you can try chart type from ASP tag